# SQL SERVER Replacing the null value in dynamic PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-pivot

Good day/night to all.
I'm new in stored procedure, i have lack of experience and understanding when it comes to stored procedure. I tried the other tutorial and answers but i don't know why my query wasnt working when using isnull(payment,'0') or coalesce(payment,'0').

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max) = '[2013-04-01],[2013-04-02],[2013-04-03],[2013-04-04],[2013-04-05],[2013-04-06]';
declare @name as nvarchar(max) = 'Derichel'
set @sql =
'SELECT pid, [Fullname], ' + @sql + '
FROM
(SELECT pid, [Fullname], payment, dateregistration
from tbl_Personal
) AS s
PIVOT
(
min(payment)
FOR dateregistration IN (' + @sql + ')
) AS pvt
where [Fullname] = ''' + @name + '''
order by pid'
execute sp_executesql @sql;
```

Some answer and tutorials have fixed column inside IN ().
My @sql has been set to different date(it depends on user input from gui).

How can i replace the null value to 0?

the output of above code is

```
pid Fullname [2013-04-01] [2013-04-02] [2013-04-03] [2013-04-04] [2013-04-05] [2013-04-06]

6   Derichel     NULL         NULL          NULL         NULL        NULL           0
```

i want to replace the null to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the NULL values because there are no rows for the dates.  When you try to include the `ISNULL` function on the root query (`SELECT ... FROM tbl_Personal`), there is nothing to modify (the row doesn't exist).

The NULL values appear as a result of the `PIVOT` operation, so you need to apply the `ISNULL` after the data is pivoted.  Another way to look at it is to apply the `ISNULL` to the definition of the final results, which is the first `SELECT` clause.

Here's the SQL statement without the formatting for a dynamic pivot query.

```
SELECT pid, [Fullname],
  ISNULL([2013-04-01], 0) AS [2013-04-01],
  ISNULL([2013-04-02], 0) AS [2013-04-02],
  ISNULL([2013-04-03], 0) AS [2013-04-03],
  ISNULL([2013-04-04], 0) AS [2013-04-04],
  ISNULL([2013-04-05], 0) AS [2013-04-05],
  ISNULL([2013-04-06], 0) AS [2013-04-06]
FROM
(SELECT pid, [Fullname], payment, dateregistration
from tbl_Personal
) AS s
PIVOT
(
min(payment)
FOR dateregistration IN ([2013-04-01],[2013-04-02],[2013-04-03],[2013-04-04],[2013-04-05],[2013-04-06])
) AS pvt
where [Fullname] = 'Derichel'
order by pid
```

For the dynamic query, you won't be able to use the @SQL variable in both places that you use it now.  The first instance would contain the `ISNULL` function calls, which are not allowed in the second instance (`FOR dateregistration IN...`).

Comment: how can i change the columns inside the IN () if it has fixed column name?

Comment: You can still use a similar technique where you construct the the SELECT clause in the @SQL variable, but you need to construct the FOR ... IN clause with a different variable.