# SQL Server : replacing the null value with dynamic PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, isnull

My query is

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX),@sql varchar(max)

SET @cols = STUFF(
   (SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(w) AS [text()]
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT voucherName AS W 
          FROM tbl_Acc_Voucher 
          WHERE voucherType = 'Sales Invoice') AS W
    ORDER BY W
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, N'');

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT voucherName,taxAmount FROM tbl_Acc_SalesMaster AS SM
    INNER JOIN tbl_Acc_Voucher AS V ON SM.voucherTypeId = V.voucherId  
    WHERE SM.invoiceNo=  ''' + @invoiceNo + ''' ) AS I
    PIVOT(SUM(taxAmount) FOR voucherName IN (' + @cols + N')) AS PIVOTTED;
    '

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to get the tax amount with null value as 0

Comment: You could call out all your columns instead of the `select *` and then replace the column name that you want 0 values as `ISNULL(ColumnName, 0)`... if that's not what you're looking for, maybe explain the question instead of just giving us a query and expecting us to know where the problem is.

Comment: here the columns is not static,so i cant select columns intead of * ,thats the problem i have facing.voucher name column is dynamic in this case,that i will take from @cols

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL SERVER Replacing the null value in dynamic PIVOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878972/sql-server-replacing-the-null-value-in-dynamic-pivot)